# Installing provisioning profile on device does nothing xcode 6

Tags: iphone, xcode6, provisioning-profile

I have a valid provisioning profile, the program I'm running works fine on one of my iPhones. However, for some reason I cannot add it to my other iPhone. Here's how it looks:

[image: Show provisioning profile]
Show provisioning profile

[image: Click to add one]
Click to add one

[image: Select my provisioning profile]
Select my provisioning profile

[image: Aaaaaand nothing happens]
Aaaaaand nothing happens

Has anyone else experience a similar problem or does anyone know what might be the solution? As of just now it just seems that xcode is unresponsive.

Comment: I had the same problem on iOS 9.3.3, but when I rebooted the iPad I could see the provisioning certificate in XCode.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rkey, I had this same problem. If you haven't found a solution, this is how I solved mine.
Instead of trying to install a provisioning profile by yourself, run the app on the device without trying to set it up yourself. Now, if I'm not mistaken, you'll get the "no provisioning profile found for this executable" message or something like that.

You need to change the Code Signing Identities in the build settings of your Xcode6.
Change everything [Code signing identity, Debug, Any SDK, Any iOS SDK, Release, Any iOS SDK)to iOS Developer and set Provisioning Profile to Automatic.

After that, if you try to run the app on the phone again, the prompt will give you an option to "Fix Issue" and clicking on "fix issue" solves the problem.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Save my hair. Thanks @etana

Comment: This should be accepted answer! Helps me with Xcode 6.3 and iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: It's been a long while now and I can't remember exactly how I solved this, but I'm sure it was something along these lines if not exactly like this. I remember looking at this answer at least, so thank you very much =)

Comment: @etana, I have same problem. Where can I set them ?

Answer (score 1):

- Go to apple portal and add all the required devices there.
- Then go to the provisioning profile you want to download, edit it and make sure the following things:
- The App ID associated with the provisioning profile and your App ID in the info.plist is the same.
- All the required devices are included in this profile(they are checked marked for the profile).
- Check the associated provisioning profile certificate is valid and you have a private key pair for that certificate.
- In xcode settings select the provisioning profile and code signing
  identity(the certifcate) for the scheme you are running the
  application.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Sadly, that has already been done and it gives me the classic error "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"

Comment: did you add you device UDID in this provsioning profile?

Comment: I thought I did, but I just remembered that this phone is not my colleagues old phone but a new one, so it has a new UDID. Thank you!

However, I tried adding it now and there is still no difference.

Comment: I'm uninstalling xcode 6, it's brought nothing but pain and agony. I'll update you on the situation when I've installed and tested with xcode 5 instead.

Comment: Nope, still the same problem: "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"

Comment: You need to re-download the provisioning profile after adding the device.  Also, make sure the app id set up with the provisioning profile matches the bundle ID of the app you are building.  If not using any special entitlements (iCloud, push notifications), you can use wildcards for the app id on Apple's developer site.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for XCode 10 ...
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52434756/3216970

Ran into this w/an Ionic app initially created w/XCode 9. 
Absolutely none of the usual fixes for automatic/manual profiles or certificates worked.

The issue was with XCode 10's "new & improved" Build System. It just doesn't work w/older projects, and none of the error messages actually explain why.

Go to File -> Workspace Settings.

Change Build System to "Legacy Build System"

Now magically the Provisioning Profiles show up on your device and you can deploy the app you needed to get on a device 3 hours ago when you started messing with this provisioning BS for the umpteen-dozenth time. Thanks Apple.