# iPhone XS not recognising (apparently) valid Development Provisioning Profile

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

So trying to test an iPhone app on an iPhone XS. 
Generally with other iPhones, I just plug in the phone, tap 'Automatically manage signing' and Xcode tells me that this device is not part of this provisioning profile. I tap repair, and that does the trick. But somehow not with iPhone XS. No 'repair' button appears.

No fear, so instead I added the device manually in developer.apple.com using the new weird shorter UDID (picked it from Xcode -> Windows -> Devices -> Identifier), regenerate the provisioning profile and download the new profile to Xcode.

Great now **Xcode tells me this Profile *includes* my iPhone XS**, but then when I try to build and run I get **"A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."**

Moreover, I cannot manually add this provisioning profile to the phone by going to Windows -> Devices and -> Provisioning Profiles -> + and choosing the new profile. => Again doing this step for an iPhone SE makes the provisioning profile appear in the list, but *not* for an iPhone XS.

I also tried adding the device with the SEID code, and somehow developer.apple.com allowed me to do it, but a provisioning profile with that device ID does not recognise my iPhone XS in Xcode.

I have restarted everything (phone, computer, Xcode) several times, and cleared out various cached folders and locations.

I am pretty lost on what to do next.

Thoughts good girls and boys of Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

OMG - 6 hours later and this was answered 4 days ago. Thanks Apple. [Xcode 10: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424462/xcode-10-a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found)

Hack for now,