# Push Notifications iOS 12 Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have problem with Push Notification in XCode 10. When I run my app from XCode - debug I can receive every push but when I archive app - release I cannot receive any push. Did you have similar problem ?  I use WindowsAzureMesseging. Certificates looks Ok on site. It worked in XCode 9.

Comment: how about is your **workspace setting** for build mode? do you use `legacy build` mode?

Comment: @RobJS Currently is set New Build System not legacy build

Comment: uh-huh, then please try your build with `legacy build` mode in order to make the app include **provisioning profiles** correctly.

Comment: Plz refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424462/xcode-10-a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found

Comment: I tried but it did not work for me. Maybe I need to revoke and generate new certificate.