# Xcode couldn’t find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, ionic4

keep getting an error running:

`sudo ionic cordova build ios`

or

`sudo ionic cordova build ios -allowProvisioningUpdates`

or

`sudo ionic cordova build ios -allowProvisioningUpdates --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"`

It was previously working and stopped all of a sudden.

note: Using new build system

note: Planning build

note: Constructing build description

Build system information

> error: No profiles for ‘com.angularfire.appname’ were found: Xcode couldn’t find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching ‘com.angularfire.appname’. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target ‘Project Name’)

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Yes, I have a profile provisioned with a dev team email address.

Comment: in your app setting, enable automatic signing in Xcode under Targets of your app. If this does not work then follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424462/xcode-10-a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found

Comment: Still getting the error: 
ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
I've tried the solutions in that link.  I'm using xCode 10.2.1...it's already code signed.  This is frustrating working with iOs...so many issues that I don't have with Android.

Comment: I am also having this problem where you able to figure it out?